# Eloquent Query error Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Im i have database structure:[image]

User has relation to it self via follows_pivot table.
Im trying to get counts of users followers
[image]

and i get error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

but if i use

```
protected $with = [
    'followedUsers'
];
```

instead of $withCount it works. Any ideas?